# Form lost opacity in Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a problem with losing opacity of my form  in Mozzilla:
[image: Firefox]

What is more in Chrome everything is great:
[image]

Do exist some tolls for set my CSS3 code to each browser? it would be great when it would add additional lines with -o- -moz- ect. prefixes.

My code is nothing special...

```
.input2
{
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  width: 240px;
  height: 45px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  border-width: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
  border-color: #CCCA14;
  text-indent: 20px;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  color: #232227;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: and your code is...?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We try to help people solve errors in their code, but to do that you need to provide your code! Please read how to ask a good question in the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: OK I posted my CSS code, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try now it works, `Border style` was not defined and that's why it was not working Firefox.

You can either define it in one line or in multiple lines i.e. property of `border` as below,

```
.input2{
border-bottom : 2px solid #CCCA14;
} 

or 

.input2{
border-bottom-width : 2px;
border-color : #CCCA14;
border-style : solid;
}
```

```css
.input2
{
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  width: 240px;
  height: 45px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  border-width: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #CCCA14;
  text-indent: 20px;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  color: #232227;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline:none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input2">
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Can you tell me why is better to write each broder property in one line "border: (...)" ?

Comment: @Edenwave that's our choice how to define it as I explained above you can define them in one line or individually multiple line, welcome :-), defining in multiple line gives us more knowledge of what we are doing.